# Not able to assign sed output to a variable

Tags: unix, sed

I am not able to capture the output of sed & cut using together in a variable. Below is the code snippet of a script:

```
max=$(sed -n '1,${/$i/p;q;}' $file | cut -d "," -f2)
```

When I print the value of max it is showing blank. But the code line is working fine when I execute it in terminal only like below:

```
sed -n '1,${/$i/p;q;}' $file | cut -d "," -f2
```

I am not able to understand why the assignment is failing. Could anyone please help me out here?

Regards,
Sayantan

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to acomplish here. Clearly from `1,$` you're doing some sed processing on two lines so the pipe should give you two values which means you need an array to store those values..

Comment: @sjam yes it is giving two values but i am cutting it to get only the value of only 2nd column. I replaced $i with a string, $file with the exact filename having rows like <string>,<number> while executing it directly at terminal. It is giving output as only <number>. But inside the script that <number> is not getting assigned in the variable max.

Comment: Well, i just noticed a `q` in the `sed` which makes  `1,${/$i/p;q;}` logically wrong. sed will quit after the first line in any case and won't go to the last line. Moreover you're not suppressing the output using `-n` option which means the first line will be printed twice. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: The `sed` command will terminate after the first line of the file, because the `q` command is not predicated on anything. If you are trying to find the first line of a file that matches a pattern, try something like `grep -m 1 ${i} ${file}` instead, or combine both `grep` and `cut` like `awk -F, '/$i/ { print $2; exit}' ${file}`...

Comment: @twalberg I used awk in place of sed but still not assigning it to max.

Comment: In single quotes `$i` is not a variable, but end-of-line followed by the character i after the end-of-line (impossible).

Comment: Thanks a lot all for the information. I searched a more and find out that $i should be in single quote to be used in sed. Now it working fine.

Comment: @WalterA Ah, yes, thanks for catching that.... Should be `awk -F, "/$i/ { print \$2; exit }"`, because then `$2` _is_ a variable which is undesired. You could also do `awk -v i="${i}" -F, '$0 ~ i { print $2; exit }', passing the variable in on the command line, but such variables don't work inside `/.../`, so the matching clause has to take a different form...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments (and worked out for OP):

In single quotes $i is not a variable, but end-of-line followed by the character i after the end-of-line (impossible).